# Python CGI script hangs with uWSGI trying to read sys.stdin

Tags: python, json, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to simply read json data passed to a python cgi script, but it hangs when I call sys.stdin. I started uWSGI with --honour-stdin and it made no difference. I'm using nginx -> uWSGI with the cgi plugin.

```
data = json.load(sys.stdin)
print "Status: 200 OK"
print "Content-Type: application/json"
print "Length:", len(data)
print ""
print data
```

Edit: If I limit the number of characters it reads it won't hang. So it's waiting for an EOF. Is there some uWSGI setting I'm missing?

Comment: Why do you use CGI instead of WSGI?! There are very lightweight WSGI libraries/frameworks such as Werkzeug or Flask.

Comment: Because I inherited a repo of old cgi scripts that I need to get working with a new server. If I had my choice I would rewrite them all in Flask. But thanks for your insight.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with a little bit of context.

Here's a [description of the CGI protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). Two highlights from the page:

1. Traditional CGI will invoke the perl/python/... interpreter separately for each request.
2. FastCGI keeps the interpreter alive:

> *FastCGI allows a single, long-running process to handle more than one user request while keeping close to the CGI programming model, retaining the simplicity while eliminating the overhead of creating a new process for each request.*

Your problem is: stdin is not terminated (EOF) after each request. Keeping the link open is actually a good idea for the performance. Besides, the HTTP connection in front may also be *keepalive*.

I learned from [this page](http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgi/) a way to check for end-of-request through the fastCGI per-request environment variables. They may be available through os.environ

```
# read until EOF set in environment
while not os.environ.get("stdin_eof", False):
    buf += sys.stdin.read(1)
```

Another idea may be to use an incremenal JSON parser like `ijson`.

Comment: I know it's not EOF terminated, that's why I updated my question. How are these requests terminated then? Surely it's not simply a timeout condition. Somehow Flask and Werkzeug manage to work.

I know about Flask and Werkzeug and I've used them extensively, this is not the answer to my question.

Comment: Interestingly, so long this code was with the incorrect logic. Found it translated to the different languages with the same error :) `os.environ.get("stdin_eof", True)` should be `os.environ.get("stdin_eof", False)`. I have edited answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use `os.environ['CONTENT_LENGTH']` environment variable to read exact number of bytes as a workaround for stdin not being terminated by CGI lib.

```
import os

if not os.environ['CONTENT_LENGTH']:
    data = {}
else:
    post_length = int(os.environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'])
    # post_length stores byte count, but stdin.read, apparently, takes the character count
    post_string = sys.stdin.buffer.read(post_length).decode('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(post_string)
```

Assuming your text is encoded in utf-8.

Comment: Needed to remove the `.buffer` part, but otherwise this seems to work correctly for me.